# Select API times out at 9600 baud rate

Tags: linux, select, serial-port, intel, uart

I am reading the data from the serial/UART, with 9600 baud rate (my 115200 baud rate is working fine)

I wrote the below code, but the select API every time gives time out, it requires timeout more than 2 seconds, that is not desirable. As I have 2048 bytes of data so within 100 ms I should able to get some data, but I think select API is not receiving interrupts, even though Rx buffer of serial has some data to process.

NOTE: the same piece of code working fine on beaglebone black, while not on intel atom-3900 / Kernel used is linux-intel 4.9.

Code:

```
int main(void)
{
  int   ret;
  char  buf[1280];
  fd_set m_Inputs;  // fd_set for the select call for com input
  int   m_maxFD;   // max FD for select() call.

  struct timeval tv;
  /*Open Serial port in non blocking mode*/
  int fd1;
  fd1 = open("/dev/ttyS1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);

  /* get the termios structure */
  struct termios options;

  tcgetattr(fd1, &options);  // Get the current options for the port...

  // Set the baud rates...
  cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);
  cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);

  // Enable the receiver and set local mode...
  options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD | CS8);
  options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;  // ignore parity
  options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;  // 1 stop bit (2 if set)
  options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;   // clear the size bits
  options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; //No hard flow control
  options.c_cflag &= ~HUPCL;   //Hang Up on last Close
  options.c_cflag |= CS8;      // reset the size to 8 bits / char
  options.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
  options.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
  options.c_oflag = 0;
  options.c_lflag = 0;       //ICANON;
  // Set the new options for the port...
  tcsetattr(fd1, TCSANOW, &options);

  cout << endl << "FD1 = " << fd1 << endl;

  while (1)
  {

        fd_set rfds;  // fd_set for the select call for com input

        FD_ZERO(&rfds);
        FD_SET(fd1, &rfds);

        tv.tv_sec = 0;
        tv.tv_usec = 100000;

        ret = select(fd1 + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

        if (ret > 0)
        {
          ret = read(fd1, buf, 127);
          buf[ret] = '\0';
          cout << buf;

        }else{

            cout << "Time OUT" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: *every time gives time out*.  Do you mean it gets stuck in an infinite loop and *never* makes a `read` system call?  Or are you saying it prints "Time OUT" ~20 times before making a `read` system call?

Comment: @PeterCordes I am getting Time OUT, before making a read system call.